# Revert to MainActivity after pausing/exiting on SecondActivity

Tags: android, onresume, onpause

I am trying to create an app with several activities.

The starting activity (MainActivity) acts as a directory or the starting page to the link to the other activities.

One of the activity in question (SecondActivity) is the activity where the gameplay essentially takes place. Its limited with a countdowntimer.

My concern is, when in the middle of the SecondActivity (or any other activity apart from MainActivity), if the SecondActivity is paused or stopped for whatever reason, I intend for the app to resume on MainActivity instead of the last Activity it was at (e.g. SecondActivity).

I have tried putting the following inside the OnResume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  Intent revrt = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
  revrt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  startActivity(revrt); 
  finish();
  super.onResume();
}
```

but the above redirects back to MainActivity immediately after launching SecondActivity. Obviously, I want SecondActivity to play out and do what its suppose to do, only to revert back to MainActivity in the event the player pause/stops (e.g launch another app, phone call etc). The reason for this is that SecondActivity tracks the score for the session and is limited by a predetermined time, and if the player could exit the app and come back to continue where he left off, it becomes a cheat for higher scores.

Is there anyway to automatically revert back to MainActivity upon restart if the SecondActivity is stopped/paused for whatever reason previously?

Comment: You should implement that not on onResume but on onPause() or onDestroy()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can declare a Boolean variable which indicates if the secondActivity is launched or not .. if it not launched yet set mIsLaunched = true and if it launched launch the MainActivity

```
Boolean mIsLaunched = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mIsLaunched){
      Intent revrt = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
      revrt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(revrt); 
      finish();
    } else {
        mIsLaunched = true;
    }
}
```

use this method to save the value before exit

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("IS_LAUNCHED", mIsLaunched);
}
```

and to get the value again use

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mIsLaunched = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("IS_LAUNCHED");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've given it a try before you suggested it. But it doesnt work. I suspect the session's boolean record does not exist once the user exits the activity, so upon going back to the SecondActivity, it could not 'recall'.

Comment: I edited my answer to be able to save the value before exit the activity

Answer (score 0):

If MainActivity exists always in back stack, you could start SecondActivity as `startActivityForResult(intent);`
and after catch result in MainActivity (depending on result you can reset it)

[Getting a Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 0):

As you said you want to call Main Activity when Second Activity goes paused or stopped.

So you should call Main Activity in onStop and onPause method instead of in onResume method. Because onResume method of Second Activity will always called when this activity will come on foreground.

Like...

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
Intent revrt = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
revrt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(revrt); 
finish();
super.onPause();
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I've tried it at onPause as you suggested. However, upon exiting the app, the app relaunches itself automatically back to MainActivity. That may annoy the user after he has chosen to exit the app.

Comment: just finish the MainActivity when you calls SecondActivity from MainActivity..and of course remove onResume method code..